# Redux: What is a correct way to add items in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a question for you, imaging there is an initial state like this,

```
const initialState = {
  services: [],
  service: {},
  loading: true
};
```

And I need to add new service to a state, sometimes I add a new item in the following way,

```
case ADD_SERVICE:
      return {
        ...state,
        service: payload,
        loading: false
      };
```

And sometimes I add like that,

```
case ADD_SERVICE:
      return {
        ...state,
        services: [...state, payload],
        loading: false
      };
```

Both work but sometimes one of them is buggy could you explain to me, why both work? And what is a preferred method.

Comment: `sometimes one of them is buggy` - can you please elaborate on this? It's good information to know 1) what the bug is and 2) which one of them is buggy

Comment: Added item does not appear immediately, for example, what is a right way to do?

Comment: That seems like a problem with your component(s) not re-rendering itself rather than redux - can you use a debugger (such as React Native Debugger) to verify that the redux store/state is actually being updated?